# Destroy the session file in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

As we all know, we can use the function session_destory() to delete the session file in PHP.But I do not know how to delete session file in Laravel due to the reason that the author rewrites the session module. Expecting your answers.

Comment: All you need to know is here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session

Comment: the session files will delete themselves over time

Comment: yes ,it will delete themselves @lagbox.But i want to figure out the way that can delete it manual

Answer (score 2):

A handy route I use while in **development** only:

```
Route::get('/flush', function () {
    Session::flush();
    return redirect('/login');
})->name('flush');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this

```
Session::flush();
```

in Laravel to destroy all the session.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Session flush as shown below:

Session::flush(); // destroy all the session.

Comment: it is not work for me. what i want is destory the session file from disk but not just delete one or more field in the session array.

Comment: The documentation says: `If you would like to remove all data from the session, you may use the flush method.`, which is already mentioned a couple of times here.

If I would have to destroy the file, I would just write helper method which deletes the file.

But if you just fine that the Session array is empty, use `flush()`.

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer by reading the original code in laravel framwork!

```
session()->getHandler()->destroy();
```

I hope it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the session storage option in files and if you finding difficulties flushing sessions from coding , It happens sometime .
Then you ultimate solution go directly to the files where it is being stored and delete the file and you see your all session will be gone for good.

session files are  stored in following path with random chars.

> yourfoldername/storage/framework/sessions/